# Django Admin - Accessing New Model gives 500 error

Tags: django, heroku, model, internal-server-error

I created a Django app with one Model initially, and hosted the site successfully with Heroku. I've since added another Model, have run makemigrations and migrate commands, and pushed code to Heroku.  Everything appears to be working fine, I can even see the new Model listed on the Admin portal.  However, when I click the model, or try to add a new instance of the model, I am thrown and internal service 500 error.

I've turned DEBUG to True, and I am seeing this: relation "my_model" does not exist.

The other model I have still works, even when I delete all instances.

Please help

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Model1, Model2

models = [Model1, Model2]

for model in models:
    admin.site.register(model)
```

```
from django.db import models

class Model1(models.Model):
    field1
    field2
    field3
    field4
    field5

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_title

class Model2(models.Model):
    field1
    field2
    field3
    field4

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_title
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to reference a foreign key somewhere that doesn't exist - can you share your admin.py and models.py files?

Comment: I just updated, thanks for taking the time.  None of the fields specified in my models are foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks - still hard to say what the issue is - can you share the full traceback of the error?

Comment: Did you run migration commands (i.e. `makemigrations` and `migrate`) on your production server? Because your error says that your new table is not accessible because it does not exists. Please run these commands on your production server and see if it works.

Comment: I have run the makemigrations and migrate commands on the production server, and not working.  Both state no changes to apply when running them.

Comment: I still haven't found the reason why the migrations initially didn't create the new model database.  However I used a work around by just running python manage.py dbshell on the production server and creating the table and fields myself.  I will watch carefully the next time I make changes to the Models to see how things are migrated in.